# Exec proc with variables taken from c# text box's

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, stored-procedures

I have a basic UI with a button that takes 3 variables.

[image]

Upon clicking the `Update Profile Class` button the following executes:

```
private void buttonUpdateProfileClass_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int ID = Convert.ToInt32(recordID.Text);
    int oldPC = Convert.ToInt32(oldProfileClass.Text);
    int NewPC = Convert.ToInt32(newProfileClass.Text);


    string connstr = @"Data Source=(local)\MydbName ;Persist Security Info=False;";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
    conn.Open();
    string query;
    query = "exec updateclass 'ID','oldPC','NewPC'";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);   

    cmd.Dispose();
    conn.Close();
    conn.Dispose();
    MessageBox.Show("Profile Class updated");

}
```

I have a stored proc which contains the following SQL (this works as I have tested it in SSMS)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[updateclass]
   @ID int,
   @NEWCLASS int,
   @OLDCLASS int    
    AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    update dbo.TEST_TABLE
    set CLASS = @NEWCLASS
    where ID = @ID AND CLASS = @OLDCLASS
```

What I want is for the user to input the ID they are concerned with, state the Old Profile Class, and state the New Profile Class. This should then run the proc and update the table, but it is not working. I am fairly new to stored procs and C# so some advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at using `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@Param, @ParamValue)` also look at how to call a StoredProcedure from C# there are a lot of examples on this current page if you start browsing the Links under the `Related` section to the right of the page here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void buttonUpdateProfileClass_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    int ID = Convert.ToInt32(recordID.Text);
    int oldPC = Convert.ToInt32(oldProfileClass.Text);
    int NewPC = Convert.ToInt32(newProfileClass.Text);


    string connstr = @"Initial Catalog=myDB;Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
    conn.Open();

    var cmd= new SqlCommand("dbo.updateclass", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NEWCLASS", NewPC);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OLDCLASS", oldPC); 

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cmd.Dispose();
    conn.Close();
    conn.Dispose();
    MessageBox.Show("Profile Class updated");
}
```

Comment: Apart from that does everything else look as it should?

Comment: I would recommend changing your example to use `Parameters.AddWithValue` this way the DB can do all of the work in regards to handling the datatypes

Comment: @nirmus When I click the button it hangs for about 10 seconds and then give me A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified

Comment: it means that your connection string is wrong. Sample connection string: "Data Source=`server\instance`; Initial Catalog=`database_name`; Integrated Security=SSPI;"

Comment: This sorted it: string connstr = @"Initial Catalog=myDB;Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;";